# Jaegers Tabs select tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I purchased Jaegers tabs (http://codecanyon.net/item/tabs-seo-mobile-friendly/3225560) because they look very clean; however the support at the website is very lacking and the person has not answered any support questions for over a year. I am new to HTML5 and jQuery and really don't understand the documentation. I'm trying to figure out how to call a tab programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to one of the `a` elements, then you can trigger a `click` event through jQuery.

example:

`<a id="fancy_link" >Fancy</a>`

`$('#fancy_link').trigger('click');`

In the case of the code on the main code on http://jaegers-ui.com/tabs/, it looks as if it puts an `a` element inside an `h1`element inside a `section` element that has an `id` on it, so you can easily do

`$('section#effects h1 a').trigger('click'); //This will trigger a click event on the link inside a link inside an h1, inside the section element with id=effects`